# python librairie winexpect don't work

Tags: python, easy-install, pexpect

i tried to use winexpect librairie winexpect but it's fail on windows !

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> pexpect.spawn(" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.6.egg\pexpect.py", line
 429, in __init__
    self._spawn (command, args)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.6.egg\pexpect.py", line
 527, in _spawn
    self.pid, self.child_fd = pty.fork()
 NameError: global name 'pty' is not defined
```

But works on linux:

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> pexpect.spawn(' ')
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7f5330c78610>
```

I've install with easy_install on both platform.

```
>:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install.exe winpexpect
Searching for winpexpect
Best match: winpexpect 1.5
Processing winpexpect-1.5-py2.6.egg
winpexpect 1.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for winpexpect
Finished processing dependencies for winpexpect
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have winexpect installed, you can use it this way:

```
import winpexpect
winexpect.winspawn(' ')
```